# Pandas Dataframe change value conditionally on arithmetic distance

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with weighs in column 'a'. I want to change the weighs only if they change by more than let say 0.05 (in both directions)
and save the resulting the column 'a_1'. Is it possible to do this without using a loop?

```
date            a     a_1
2017-06-30     0.72   0.72  
2017-07-01     0.74   0.72    
2017-07-02     0.71   0.72
2017-07-03     0.70   0.72
2017-07-04     0.67   0.72
2017-07-05     0.66   0.66    --> difference is -0.06 < -0.05    
2017-07-06     0.65   0.66 
2017-07-07     0.76   0.76    --> difference is +0.10 > +0.05 
2017-07-08     0.77   0.76
2017-07-09     0.78   0.76
2017-07-10     0.74   0.76
2017-07-11     0.69   0.70    --> difference is -0.07 < -0.05
2017-07-12     0.73   0.70
2017-07-13     0.73   0.70
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas' `apply` method, is that preferable to a for loop for you?

Unfortunately, it would mean changing a global variable inside a function. If you can live with that, the following works:

```
number_to_compare = 0

def get_weight(row):
    global number_to_compare
    if abs(row.a - number_to_compare) > 0.05:
        number_to_compare = row.a
        return row.a
    return number_to_compare

df['a_1'] = df.apply(get_weight, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               a    a_1
date        
2017-06-30  0.72    0.72
2017-07-01  0.74    0.72
2017-07-02  0.71    0.72
2017-07-03  0.70    0.72
2017-07-04  0.67    0.72
2017-07-05  0.66    0.66
2017-07-06  0.65    0.66
2017-07-07  0.76    0.76
2017-07-08  0.77    0.76
2017-07-09  0.78    0.76
2017-07-10  0.74    0.76
2017-07-11  0.69    0.69
2017-07-12  0.73    0.69
2017-07-13  0.73    0.69
```